# ¿Que son los decoradores en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera que alguien me ayude explicandome, ¿que son los decoradores en javascript?

Hoy estuve leyendo un poco sobre patrones de diseño y justo me tope con decoradores, indignado un poco vi que existe un feature sobre este tema.
No se si ya está aprobado para salir como una versión estable para los navegadores, pero con babel algunos ya lo utilizan. Este es el ejemplo que estuve estudiando y hasta ahora me cuesta entender :

```js
class Math {
  @log
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

function log(target, name, descriptor) {
  var oldValue = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function() {
    console.log(`Calling "${name}" with`, arguments);

    return oldValue.apply(null, arguments);
  };

  return descriptor;
}

const math = new Math();

math.add(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hace el decorador en este caso es añadir la funcionalidad de la función log a la función add.

Esto se puede hacer de otras formas, te pongo un ejemplo para que lo entiendas mejor.

Pongamos que tienes la clase

```
class Math {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Ahora vamos a crear un decorador que añade funcionalidad a una función

```
function decoratorLog(f) {
  var oldValue = f;

  f = function() {
      console.log(`Calling "${f.name}" with`, arguments);
      return oldValue.apply(null, arguments);
  }
}
```

Y ahora asignamos el decorador a la función Math.add

```
Math.prototype.add = decoratorLog(Math.prototype.add);
```

Cuando llames al método add, además de sumar los dos números se mostrara en el log de la consola algo así

> Calling "add" with Arguments(2) [1, 2, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]

Espero te sirva la respuesta